# Generic Function to create dynamic grid that can be called from multiple other functions returning array

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a Vf page that has 5 remote actions that all return a list of accounts. I want to create a generic function that can insert row in the table.
So far, I have created the table. The list returned from each remote action is saved in a variable result. 
Now to populate the columns I want to use the for each logic and traverse each record returned in the list. How do we reference the values in a particular record of the  list when using result.forEach(function(record)

Since the list returned is an sObject list so lets assume it has following accounts:

```
Acc Id Acc Name
1223   TestAcc1
2345   TestAcc2

result.forEach(function(record) {
// Insert row 
var LastRow   = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);
// Insert cells
var Cell1  = LastRow.insertCell(0);
var Cell2  = LastRow.insertCell(1);
//Setting cell values
Cell1.innerHTML = record[How to get the first value in the list here?];
Cell2.innerHTML = record[How to get the second value in the list here?];
```

Answer (score 1):

Won't this work ?

```
Cell1.innerHTML = record['Id'];
Cell2.innerHTML = record['Name'];
```

**Update:**

Since you are asking for generic way you can try this:

```
var columns = Object.keys(record[0]);
result.forEach(function(record) {
    var LastRow = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);
    columns.forEach(function(column,index) {
        var cell = LastRow.insertCell(index);
        cell.innerHTML = record[column];
    }
}
```